# Is there a thread-safe version of GetFullPathName?

Tags: c++, winapi

The MSDN documentation advises against using `GetFullPathName()` in both multi-threaded applications and shared libraries - unfortunately, I'm building a multi-threaded shared library.

Specifically, I'm looking to convert double-dot components, such that given a current directory of `"C:\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC"`, the path `"..\..\FolderX\FolderY"` would yield `"C:\FolderX\FolderY"`.

Although I can write one from scratch, I'm hoping to find a quicker solution, and, one that's already tried and tested.

**Edit**

After reviewing my specs, I can require the caller to specify a base folder, rather than relying on the current directory. However, I'd still have to convert the double-dots, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Please note that the project requirements exclude third-party libraries, such as Boost and QT, unless the algorithm can be copied completely into the final solution.

Comment: I _think_ the multithreaded restriction is because the current directory is global.  A different thread can change the current directory, resulting in an unexpected full path name.

Comment: Yes, the documentation does warn against that. In fact I was originally thinking of just surrounding the call with a global critical section, but I don't want the performance hit, especially since the routine(s) are critical and called a lot.

Comment: @Luxabundus you can surround it with all the critical sections you want, but the logical problem won't go away. The current directory is a global property of the process, so if you have different threads changing it GetFullPathName is the least of your problems - relative paths _in general_ lose meaning, period. A multithreaded application shouldn't change the current directory, period, and in that case GetFullPathName has no problems.

Comment: @Matteo - yeah, was just thinking that after I submitted the comment - I'd have to cover all the APIs that affect the current directory. The problem is that, as a library used by other apps, there's no control over if/when the caller changes the current directory. According to my specs, however, I can require the caller to specify a base folder, instead of using the current directory. But I'd still have to write the double-dot conversion, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: There's also the general concern that the result may be out-of-date the moment it's returned if another thread in your process or in a separate process might be in the midst of deleting/moving/renaming directories and files.  But that's a general problem not specific to this API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `GetFullPathName` that makes it thread-unsafe is that it relies on current directory.

So you need to use `PathCombine` (or improved version like `PathCchCombineEx`) and pass something instead of current directory yourself.

Comment: Ah, that's the one... PathCchCombine works perfectly. You've saved me from a lot frustration. Many thanks, Alexander!

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, the not-recommended-for-multithread warning of `GetFullPathName` stems from the fact that the current directory is a property that is global of the process, and if you change it without synchronization relative paths lose meaning. It's not like the provided API is lazy about this and an alternative implementation of `GetFullPathName` could save you in any way - it's relative paths that are broken by design (if the current path is changed) in a multithreaded environment.

Long story short: ***this isn't something from which you can defend yourself***, just use `GetFullPathName`<sup>1</sup>. If your library client passes you a relative path, then it's implicitly promising that it won't change the current path in the meanwhile, as it would make the path it passed to you completely meaningless; you would have the exact same problem if you were to use that path in any other way (included opening it).

---

1. If you have to. Generally, the more applications just pass around paths as opaque blobs, the less they break when they receive valid but "exotic" paths.